# Get values from a List inside a dictionary, created in c# in a view (js)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

to finish my last question, I have a model class

```
    public class EvolutionGraphicData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AddedDate { get; set; }
}
```

and a dictionary (string, List()) coded in code behind (C#).  I serialize it, to be able to access it from my view

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dicForGraph);
        return json;
```

and pass it in a ViewBag.

Now, in my view I get:
1: [object,Object],[object,Object], etc, which is fine

my question would be, how to access those objects, to get the real value from them (like in 1: it should be "PersonName":"Per1","AddedDate":"1466650800000", "PersonName":"Per1","AddedDate":"1467255600000"

This is what I have in the view:

```
$(function () {
        var dataForGrap = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataList);
        $.each(dataForGrap, function(key, value) { 
            alert(key + ': ' + value);
        });
    })
```

*** As per Stephen recommendation, I´m adding some clarification:

dicForGraph is a dictionary.
I have a DB with a table. It has Names and total amount of phone numbers, and another with Names, phone numbers and date added. So I´m using a dictionary to group together all phone adding dates under each of the names:

```
var dicForGraph = new Dictionary<string, List<EvolutionGraphicData>>()
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `dicForGraph`? And why are you using a `Dictionary`?

Comment: dicForGraph is a dictionary.  I have in a DB a table with Names and total amount of phone numbers, and another with Names, phone numbers and date added.  So I´m using a dictionary to group together all phone adding dates under each of the names: Dictionary<string, List<EvolutionGraphicData>> dicForGraph = new Dictionary<string, List<EvolutionGraphicData>>();

Comment: Edit your question with the details (not in comments)

Comment: Hey guys... What is the point of adding some negative points if YOU ARE NOT EVEN ANSWERING MY QUESTION? Are you trying to get me out of the page??????

Comment: `value` is an array of objects, so you need a second `$.each()` to loop through the `List<EvolutionGraphicData>` property

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a way to pass your dictionary to your JavaScript as JSON?

One way to do this is to write an element like this to your page:

```
<script id="myData" type="application/json">
{yourJson}
</script>
```

and then

```
var dataForGrap = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('myData').textContext);
```

If you try to do this:

```
var dataForGrap = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataList);'
```

then single quotes in your JSON will break the script. (Learned from painful experience.)

To write that JSON to your view you can do this (using Newtonsoft Json.NET)

```
<script id="myData" type="application/json">
@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.DataList))
</script>
```

Or if your object is already serialized:

```
<script id="myData" type="application/json">
@Html.Raw(yourAlreadySerializedJson)
</script>
```

Comment: I have it serialized already and I am able to retrieve the date from it.  My issue is I am not able to get the data from the List inside the dictionary. I keep getting [object,Object]: